# PHP/MySQL: Function who strip

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working with PHP to select somme data on a database. I use this code

```
function recupererCases_mysql($connexion) {
    $cases = $connexion->query('SELECT questionnaire FROM code_machine_dict');
    foreach ($cases as $row) {
    print $row['questionnaire'] . "\n";}
    }
```

but, it display:

1 7247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LEMONDE 1 3247703226635 DS_ST_W_COOD_7LEFIGARO 16247703226635 DS_ST_W67 OJ 1 2247703226635 DS_ST_W12 1 4247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_5O 1 8247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LE FIGARO 110247703226635 DS_ST_W_CTO_1 NOUVEAU QUESTIONNAIR 1 5247703226635 DS_ST_W4 EMONDE 1 1247703226635 DS_ST_W1 LE 1 6247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LE NOUVELLISTE 1 9247703226635 DS_ST_W_CTO_8 I

rather than how it's in the database:

```
1 7247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LEMONDE 
1 3247703226635 DS_ST_W_COOD_7LEFIGARO 
16247703226635 DS_ST_W67 OJ 
1 2247703226635 DS_ST_W12 
1 4247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_5O 
1 8247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LE FIGARO 
110247703226635 DS_ST_W_CTO_1 NOUVEAU QUESTIONNAIR 
1 5247703226635 DS_ST_W4 EMONDE 
1 1247703226635 DS_ST_W1 LE 
1 6247703226635 DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LE NOUVELLISTE 
1 9247703226635 DS_ST_W_CTO_8 I
```

With the help of Dagon, i format the results, but there's another problem with the function

It return:
 1 1247703226635 DS_ST_W1 LE

instead of this who's recorded natively in the database:

1 1247703226635                   DS_ST_W1      LE

please any help!

Comment: `print $row['questionnaire'] . "<br>\n";` will give you line breaks and clean html.

Comment: Please see modifications in question for more helps. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers expect HTML. for HTML a line break is:  `<br>`.

or keep the current code but wrap the block in `<pre> ..</pre>`

Comment: Thanks a lot Dagon for formatting and this good advise.                          It work with  <br>                                                                           function recupererCases_mysql($connexion) {
    $cases = $connexion->query('SELECT questionnaire FROM code_machine_dict');
    foreach ($cases as $row) {
    print $row['questionnaire'] . "<br>";}
    }

Comment: Please see modifications in question for more helps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tr_user same answer browsers expect HTML you have spaces? or tabs? you have to replace them

Comment: When i view page source on Chrome, they are displayed normally </style>
</head>
<body>
1 7247703226635                  DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LEMONDE<br>
1 3247703226635                  DS_ST_W_COOD_7LEFIGARO<br>
16247703226635                  DS_ST_W67     OJ<br>
1 2247703226635                  DS_ST_W12<br>
1 4247703226635                  DS_ST_W_VICQ_5O<br>
1 8247703226635                  DS_ST_W_VICQ_1LE FIGARO<br>
110247703226635                  DS_ST_W_CTO_1 NOUVEAU QUESTIONNAIR<br>
1 5247703226635                  DS_ST_W4      EMONDE<br>

Comment: yes SOURCE=text. again BROWSER EXPECTS **HTML**